# Understanding parsing function here

Tags: python, parsing, arguments

I have googled it but it is not clear what the function `parse` is doing here. At least, I do not quite understand. Please if someone could clarify it for me, I would be grateful.

```
Data = pd.ExcelFile(filename[0])          
ncols = Data.book.sheet_by_index(0).ncols  #class book google it 
Data_df = Data.parse(0, converters={i : str for i in range(ncols-1)}, encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: What is `Data` in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that the snippet presented was preceded with

```
import pandas as pd
```

The `ExcelFile` class is described [here, in the Pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-excel-excelfile-class). The [`ExcelFile.parse`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html#pandas.ExcelFile.parse) function is a thin wrapper around [`pd.read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel); the `converters` argument is described in the last link:

> **converters** : *dict, default `None`*
>
> - Dict of functions for converting values in certain columns. Keys can either be integers or column labels, values are functions that take one input argument, the Excel cell content, and return the transformed content.

The `book` object accessed in line 2 is part of the `xlrd` package, which is the underlying implementation used by `panda` to read Excel files. It is documented [here](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-xlrd.book), and the `sheet_by_index` method [here](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.book.Book.sheet_by_index) (although those just do what you might expect); the `ncols` field in a `Sheet` is documented [here](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Sheet), and it just returns the number of columns in the sheet, ignoring trailing empty columns.

In short, `range(ncols-1)` will produce the indices of all the columns except the last one, so the converters dictionary `{i : str for i in range(ncols-1)}` has the effect of treating every column except the last as a simple string, instead of attempting to parse each cell to decide its datatype.

Comment: Yes, it definitely explains a lot! Thank you for this precious link (ExcelFile.parse) now I have a better understanding of this code :D